# discord bot hosted on glitch Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'

Tags: node.js, discord.js

i have been hosting a discord bot on glitch.com for almost a year now with no problems.
But today the bot went down. The error I get is:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
```

I have installed discord.js via the add package, and nothing changes.
 But when I do:
`npm install discord.js` 
The error changes to:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mysql2/promise'
```

If I install mysql2 then after this it goes back to the error from discord.js

EDIT:

I did something differend now. I did the npm install mysql2 and then got the error from no-keepalive, etc... I did every npm install. And now I get this error  also where can I uninstall from devDependecies?

Fixed by uninstalling all node-mudules and reinstalling with npm install

Comment: check the version of the discord.js package and uninstall it from devDependencies, dependencies, globally. Then reinstall it.

Comment: Wait. I did something differend now.
I did the npm install mysql2 and then got the error from no-keepalive, etc...
I did every npm install. And now I get this error
<TypeError: client.guilds.get is not a function>

also where can I uninstall from devDependecies?

Comment: for uninstalled in devdependencies `uninstall --save <package name>`

Comment: I get this when I do `uninstall --save discord.js` 
-su: uninstall: command not found

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that the command has to be done with npm `npm uninstall --save <package name>`

Comment: Do I need to uninstall everything what I had in dependecies? with the command? or is there a better way to uninstall all packages I ave installed?

Comment: no uninstall just discord.js but if the problem persist you can remove node_modules folder and do `npm install` for reinstall all modules.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the dependency in your `package.json` file

```
"dependencies": {
    ...,
    "discord.js": "^12.0.2"
},
```

**NOTE: This discord js version is the most recent version as of March 19th 2020**
To get the most recent version head over to https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js
and find the version number.

Comment: This is alrdy included in the package.json file